# How to calculate the distortion of molecule?

Tags: density-functional-theory, geometry

I have a set of molecules that are generated from a regular cyclohexane and have varying amounts of substitutions and double bonds. I need to compute the amount of distortion that each of these changes causes in the molecule. My current method is to calculate the average molecular plane for each molecule and compute the signed z-projected distance of each heavy atom from the molecular plane. Is this a valid way to describe distortion using geometric parameter, or is there any standard tools of descriptors already available for this task?

Comment: RMSD from a reference? Or RMSD from the projection of the reference on a plane? As long as you make clear what is your metric, that it is reasonable, whether it is bounded, and what low and high values mean, I don't think anybody would raise any particular objections.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. However, I do not think RMSD would be suitable metric, since the atoms do change from one molecule to another. For example, one can be C6H12, and the other can be C5H10N, which means that I will not have a one-to-one mapping always.

Comment: you can still compute the RMSD between the subset of atoms in common.